# How to enrich a spring controller json's response

Tags: json, spring, filtering

I've got a simple Spring MVC app where controllers are generating Json objects and returning them as Strings.

I'd like to return those json trees as-is out of the controllers and have a kind of servlet filter which will enrich them. Basically it will take the json node and move it as a child of a brand new json root. Think of a 'body' encapsulated in a complete response including also a 'head' child node that would be generated by this filter.

It is possible to do so within Spring ?

Thanks for your advices !

Answer (score 0):

I would advise instead of returning plain Strings, return POJO and convert this to JSON using HTTP Message converters (e.g. `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`) and `@ResponseBody` annotation. Then you can decorate the return object the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. From what i see, the messageconverter uses customizable objectmapper(s). I need to have the http request and response objects given as arguments to this "filter" so that i can enrich the response as needed. I'm not sure the framework allows this.